# How to tell if optional parameter in PHP method/function was set or not?

Tags: php

Assume I have a method/function with the following signature:

```
foo($bar = 0)
```

Inside ***foo***, how do I tell if **$bar** was set or not? ***isset*** will alway return a ***TRUE*** since ***$bar*** is assigned ***0*** in the event nothing is passed to ***foo***.

Checking for 0 is not an option. I need to know the difference between the parameter explicitly being set to 0 or defaulting to 0.

Comment: That's a really kludgey way for a function to behave.  `f(0)` should produce the same result, regardless of the "source" of the argument `0`.

Comment: Not if you are creating a polymorphic method that does one thing if the parameter is set and another thing if the parameter is not set.

Comment: Frank, some built in functions do this, in my case I needed to wrap substr, and when I passed the wrappers $length default argument of null to substr, I got nothing back, as substr interprets that as 0 length. Yes, it is insanely kludgey, I've come to expect nothing better of PHP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use [**func_num_args()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to specifically check for how many arguments were passed in.

```
<?php
function foo($bar = 0)
{
    echo "\nNumber of arguments: " . func_num_args();
}

  // Outputs "Number of arguments: 1"
foo(0);

  // Outputs "Number of arguments: 0"
foo();
?>
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.org/IQAM7lEz)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func_get_args). Example:

```
function foo($optional=null) {
    if (count(func_get_args()) > 0)
        echo "optional given\n";
    else
        echo "optional not given\n";
}

foo(); //optional not given
foo(null); //optional given
```

Note that the convention used for internal PHP functions is to always give optional arguments a default value and to have them have the same behavior when both argument is not given and its default value is explicitly given. If you ever find otherwise, file a bug report. This let's you do stuff like this without `if`s:

```
function strpos_wrap($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {
    return strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
}
```

This convention is more enforced is userland, as the difficulty that led you to this question has shown you. If the convention doesn't suit your needs, at least reconsider your approach. The purpose of `func_num_args`/`func_get_args` is mainly to allow variable argument functions.

Comment: This wasn't an issue when this was asked, but these days, how would this work if arguments are passed as named arguments?